# D3 multi line y-axis chart from textarea input

Tags: d3.js

I want to make multiple line chart from textarea inout. When we paste some data from excel then textarea values convers into array and used by d3 to plot the data. Now, I am confused how to apply nest() function here, as I have seen people applying it for .csv files. Or what we need to do to make it multiple line chart. Please take a look at my code.

```js
function mainData(){
var data = document.getElementById('dinput').value.trim().split('\n').map(line => {
let tokens = line.trim().split(/\s+/).map(str => Number(str, 10));
return { x: tokens[0], y: tokens[1] }
});return data;};   

document.getElementById('dinput').addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
document.getElementById('dinput').addEventListener('input', function () {
d3.select(".chart").remove();
draw();
});});

async function draw() {
const dataset = mainData();
const xAccessor = d => { return d.x; } 
const yAccessor = d => { return d.y; }
let dimensions = { width: 1280, height: 720, margins: 50,};
dimensions.ctrWidth = dimensions.width - dimensions.margins * 2
dimensions.ctrHeight = dimensions.height - dimensions.margins * 2
const svg = d3.select('#chartdiv').append("svg").classed("chart",true).attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+ dimensions.width +" "+ dimensions.height +"")
const ctr = svg.append("g").attr("transform",`translate(${dimensions.margins}, ${dimensions.margins})`)
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(dataset, yAccessor)).range([dimensions.ctrHeight, 0]).nice();
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(dataset, xAccessor)).range([0, dimensions.ctrWidth]).nice();
const lineGenerator = d3.line().x((d) => xScale(xAccessor(d))).y((d) => yScale(yAccessor(d)))
ctr.append('path').datum(dataset).attr('d', lineGenerator).attr('fill', 'none').attr('stroke', '#30475e').attr('stroke-width', 2)
ctr.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
ctr.append('g').style('transform', `translateY(${dimensions.ctrHeight}px)`).call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
}
draw()
```

```html
<textarea id="dinput">
280&#09;0.013&#09;0.013
290&#09;0.035&#09;0.013
300&#09;0.140&#09;0.013
310&#09;0.425&#09;0.313
320&#09;0.820&#09;0.013
330&#09;1.152&#09;0.013
340&#09;0.802&#09;0.013
350&#09;0.423&#09;0.013
360&#09;0.123&#09;0.013
370&#09;0.040&#09;0.013
380&#09;0.020&#09;0.013
390&#09;0.020&#09;0.831
400&#09;0.020&#09;0.013
410&#09;0.020&#09;0.013
420&#09;0.015&#09;0.013
</textarea>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```